# PDO bind params placeholders PostgreSQL conflict

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, placeholder

I am using postgres for a database, and noticed, that PDO reserves some of Postgres syntax features for variable binding, for example:

checking if hstore has a key `SELECT * FROM t WHERE store ? 'key'`

setting variable type  `SELECT id::integer from t`

How can i escape such situations? Maybe someone could share more such examples?

Comment: Please can you clarify what the issue is exactly? Are you having issues with the `?` PDO parameter placeholder?

Comment: I've found an alternative to using ? hstore parameter, so, yes. But question ask not how to solve the ? placeholder, but how to allow using it, or rather how to use both standard postgresql features and  pdo binding.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think, there is an escape mechanism for placeholders in PDO.

Workarounds:

- for casting a value in Postgres, you can use the SQL compliant version: `CAST(id AS integer)`
- for the hstore `?` operator, you can use the `exist(hstore, text)` function

[Also](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php):

> You cannot use both named and question mark parameter markers within the same SQL statement; pick one or the other parameter style.

<del>So, if you use named parameters, it should be safe to use the `?` operator, and vice versa.</del>

As it turns out, you can't. It yields error: `mixed named and positional parameters`.